# app broke after Xcode update

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a `Swift` app, with some `Objective-C` code mixed in. It was working yesterday, but this morning I updated `XCode` and now everything had gone to hell!
Firstly, after updating, I clicked the XCode popup box to allow it to upgrade my app to `Swift4`. This is where the problems started.

I have a `Swift` class called `RestClient` with the following 4 functions (among others):

```
class func getInstance() -> RestClient {
    if (gRestClient == nil) {
         let prefs:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        return RestClient(username: prefs.string(forKey: "username")!, password: prefs.string(forKey: "password")!)
    }
    return gRestClient!
}

class func getUsername() -> String {
    if (gUsername == nil) {
        let prefs:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        gUsername = prefs.string(forKey: "username")!
    }
    return gUsername!
}

class func getPassword() -> String {
    if (gPassword == nil) {
        let prefs:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        gPassword = prefs.string(forKey: "password")!
    }
    return gPassword!
}

public func getServer() -> String {
    return MAIN_SERVER;
}
```

Then in my /Objective-C/ folder, I have some more files, once of which is called `RestClientObj.m`. In here, I have this lines of code:

```
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/receipt/email/%@/%@/", [[RestClient getInstance] getServer], rrn, emailAddress];
NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", [RestClient getUsername], [RestClient getPassword]];
```

So as you can see, I'm calling the `RestClient.swift` from here. The `RestClientObj.h` is as follows:

```
#ifndef RestClientObj_h
#define RestClientObj_h


#endif /* ResClientObj_h */

@interface RestClientObj : NSObject {
}

+(BOOL) sendSMS:(NSString *)rrn mn:(NSString *)mobileNumber;

+(BOOL) sendEmail:(NSString *)rrn mn:(NSString *)emailAddress;

@end
```

This whole upgrade is causing other problems too. I have another class with the following error:

`No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'managedObjectContext'`

on the line:

```
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext]; <-ERROR
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

EDIT: Here's some code from the `AppDelegate` class:

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
    }()
```

Comment: What's the code of `AppDelegate` it's properties at least?

Comment: @Larme I've added a snippet from `AppDelegate`.

Comment: Hard to tell without your full code ... did you 1) Put `@objc` in front of the Swift `func`tions that you want to call? 2) Put `AppName-Swift.h` in the ObjC `.m` files where you have Swift func calls?

Comment: @MattH I didn't have `@objc` at the start of the functions, so that resolved it for the most part. The other thing seems that the "Upgrade Wizard" in XCode renamed my functions, eg from `authorise()` to `authoriseWithTransaction()`. Presumably so the code follows Apple's preferred naming conventions.

Comment: I am having the same issues, I cant interlink between objective c and swift classes

Comment: @pojomx Check to see that `@objc` is before every Swift function you want to be called from Objective-C. Also, make sure your Bridging Header file is correct, and is included in each Objective-C `.m` files, as @MattH said above.

Comment: @eoinzy I managed to find <my> mistake, a partner added another bridging file it was not added to the project (the one in the project was not referenced by the app) so there it was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this off.
The issue was missing the `@obj` identifier before the variable declaration to make it visible to my objective-c code, in combination with the XCode Swift Upgrade wizard renaming some functions.